# How to Create Mail Account manually by exim?

Tags: email, exim, dovecot

i have **[exim](http://www.exim.org/)** and **dovecot** in my server for mail-server

> How could i manually create email account like `user@mydomain.com` with
>   defined pass ?

- i don't want to use any pricing server software like *cPanel* or ...
- is there any free and stable program for create mail account ?
- is it better to create manually or use software?

Comment: not really a programming question, try on the systems and networking SE site

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There are several way to create ثmail accountو one of them is inserting record to database you can find more information in the following link:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-e-mail-server-with-dovecot

Comment: Those instructions are for postfux, the OP is using sexim.